# Excel worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that copies data from one sheet to another.
No problem, but I named the sheet with an emoji.

How can I tell VBA which sheet he has to use if the name of the sheet is for example:

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's surprising for me to know that you can rename the sheet with emoji.  Never heard it before....

Comment: The OP's 'emoji' gives me a Unicode value of -10180 with `AscW`. I tried `Sheet1.Name = ChrW(-10180)` but it didn't render the 'home' symbol :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AscW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262678(VS.60).aspx) function to find the appropriate unicode value for the item and use that to find the correct sheet

Comment: You need to use AscW because Asc will not return a proper value for non "regular" characters

Comment: @Robin try using the following code for negative values - `If UnicodeVal < 0 Then
        UnicodeVal = 65536 + UnicodeVal
    End If`

Answer (score 0):

To find the name of any given worksheet, activate the worksheet, open the VBA Editor (Alt+F11), open the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type the following:

```
? ActiveSheet.Name
```

If the name for some reason is nonsensical, and only consists of a single character, run `? Asc(ActiveSheet.Name)` to get the ASCII value.

Referencing an ASCII value in VBA can be done by calling `Chr(putValueHere)`, for example like this:

```
Worksheets(1).Name = Chr(50)
```

If you have a plethora of sheets, you can print all of them by running this code:

```
Sub SheetNamePrinter
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have an idea. Can I just take the sheet number?

Comment: Yes. The [Worksheets Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821537.aspx) lets you use either a string argument (the actual name of the sheet) or an integer argument (the positional index of the sheet inside the collection).